# Automatic popup when new data entry in sheet1 change a cell value in another sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I've a problem about automatic message. I have a macro that put a data entry into sheet2 (the active sheet) in column A. This entry write a new entry in sheet2 column B. Now in sheet1 (that is NOT the active sheet) this data entry (sheet2 column B) automatically updates the value in sheet1 column C (by a formula inside the cell). If the sheet1 column C reach a specific threshold (e.g. 25%) the sheet1 column D is updated and change from "Ok" state to "Not Ok" state. I want that everytime the column D status change from "Ok" to "Not Ok" an alert message is visible. Could you have any idea, please? I hope in your help!
I just tried worksheet_change in sheet1 and it works, how can I show the pop-up automatically even if I'm working into sheet2?
Thank you preventively for your kindly help!

In sheet1 this code works fine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim KeyCells As Range
 Set KeyCells = Range("list") ' range between A to D column

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
 If Cells(Target.Row, "D") = "Not Ok" Then
 MsgBox Cells(Target.Row, "A") & " is not Ok!"
 End If
End If

 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

But if I insert this code in Workbook it doesn't work

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim KeyCells As Range
 Set KeyCells = Range("list")

 Application.EnableEvents = False

If Sh.Name = "sheet1" Then
 If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("list")) Is Nothing Then
  If Cells(Target.Row, "D") = "Not Ok" Then
   MsgBox Cells(Target.Row, "A") & " is not Ok!"  
  End If
 End If
End If

 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: look into [Workbook_SheetChange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange) event

Answer (score 0):

Add the event for workbook change instead of the worksheet, add small snipet of a code which will check for the active worksheet or the Not Ok status in that cell. So you can only get the alert when those conditions are met. 
I tried this code in the Workbook code.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value
End Sub
```

Here, the code applies to all the worksheets you have in your workbook, so change in any one of them will trigger this event.
[image]
You can now modify the code to only warn when it is "Not OK" instead of all. simple if statement shoud do that.

Something like:

```vb
check=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value
if not(check="OK") then
MsgBox "Not OK"
end if
```

Comment: Thank you for yuour reply. I've just tried workbook_sheetchange but I don't understand how it works. The Sh I insert as object must be sheet1 or sheet2? The msgbox must be visible when sheet2 column D change from "Ok" to "Not Ok", but this change  just happens when there is an entry in sheet1 column A.

Comment: You don't understand how it works but it works? I have edited the answer, maybe that'll help.